# iTune, App upload warning. App references non-public selectors in : productName

Tags: app-store-connect, non-public-selectors

During the upload of my app on iTune connect I've got the following Warning :

```
The app references non-public selectors in My_application.app/My_application: productName
```

I've got some knowledge from those questions :

[The app references non-public selectors in Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10023343/the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload)

[How to debug “The app references non-public selectors” error in Apple App Loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356014/how-to-debug-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-error-in-apple-app-loader)

[Apple says The app references non-public selectors in my app. What does that mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884968/apple-says-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-my-app-what-does-that-mea)

But nothing specific on `productName`. Searching my project I found this string only in Google Analytics Libraries. I double check I've got the last version of Google Analytics.

I assume that the Apple validator robot think I'm trying to change the App name programmatically (that I'm not doing).

Does any apps have been rejected with this warning ? How can I remove this warning ?

Comment: Did Apple accept your upload? I got the same warning

Comment: I got the same warning, and yes the upload was accepted

Comment: It's not a real reject problem, don't worry, just submit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 5 Days of stress the application got accepted by Apple without any warning.

I assume it was a robot Warning well known by Apple Tester.

Answer (score 2):

Just download the latest SDK from google analytics. The problem is resolved in the latest version (at this time of answer 3.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.I removed Google Analytics sdk and use flurry .

Then everything is ok.